# Best way to do a long running schema change (or data update) in MS Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to alter the size of a column on a large table (millions of rows). It will be set to a nvarchar(n) rather than nvarchar(max), so from what I understand, it will not be a long change. But since I will be doing this on production I wanted to understand the ramifications in case it does take long.

Should I just hit F5 from SSMS like I execute normal queries? What happens if my machine crashes? Or goes to sleep? What's the general best practice for doing long running updates? Should it be scheduled as a job on the server maybe?

Thanks

Comment: Execute it directly on the server at a time with lowest traffic.

Comment: And don't just do this in production. You should copy this to a test server and make sure your script actually works. And also how long it takes. If it runs for 36 hours that might not be acceptable in a production environment and you might need to find another way of doing this.

Comment: Create an agent job. Even if your remote session to the server crashes, the job would still complete. Whereas if you were running SSMS in RDP, the session would end.

Comment: If you are worried about failure then wrap the statements in a transaction and try/catch. Then if there is some failure on the server it can be rolled back.

Comment: @Igor Running for 12 hours and having transaction roll back because RDP got booted out is not very helpful.

Comment: @ajeh - I do not recall advocating running it in SSMS. I am advocating that you should wrap your schema changes in a transaction so you do not have a partial change if there is a failure later on in the script.

Comment: Yeah, the point being, that running a huge update in a transaction does not save from a disconnected session. He wants to run just 1 update, where transaction would not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please DO NOT just hit F5.  I did this once and lost all the data in the table.  Depending on the change, the update statement that is created for you actually stores the data in memory, drops the table, creates the new one that has the change you want, and populates the data from memory.  However in my case one of the changes I made was adding a unique constraint so the population failed, and as the statement was over the data in memory was dropped.  This left me with the new empty table.

I would create the table you are changing, with the change(s) you want, as a new table.  Then select * into the new table, then re-name the tables in a single statement.  If there is potential for data to be entered into the table while this is running and that is an issue, you may want to lock the table.

Depending on the size of the table and duration of the statement, you may want to save the locking and re-naming for later, and after the initial population of the new table do a differential population of new data and re-name the tables.

Sorry for the long post.

Edit:
Also, if the connection times out due to duration, then run the insert statement locally on the DB server.  You could also create a job and run that, however it is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know. I didn't go all the way as I was mostly confident it was just a metadata change. Our server is on Azure and I ended up creating a Job to run a powershell InlineScript which executes locally on the server.